# How do you update bokeh.plotting.figure.y_axis using bokeh server

Tags: bokeh

--updated after I was able to replicate the issue and understand it a bit more.

When I set up my figure for Bokeh Server I add 25 to the y_range so I have some padding at the top for labels.

```
plot = figure(x_range=chart_data_source.data['we'],
    plot_height=250,
plot.y_range.end = max(chart_data_source.data['total']+25)
```

Later on, after I update the data source via a callback, I want to re-set the y_range.  The following line is in my update function, invoked by a change in any of the multiselect widgets.  Everything else about my figure changes just fine, but the y_range doesn't.  My attempt to update y_range:

```
plot.y_range.end = max(chart_data_source.data['total'] + 25)
```

which does not update the y_range.  Any idea how I can update my y_range in bokeh server?
Bokeh server version 1.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why my y_range wasn't being updated.  If I set y_range.max independently then I can't "re-set" it later on in the update() function. But if I set when I declare the figure then I can  update the value in my update() function. Is this expected behavior of Bokeh?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button


def populate_table_source(df):
    ds = {}
    for col in list(df):
        ds[col] = df[col]
    return ds


colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]
years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']
data = {'fruits': ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries'],
        '2015': [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016': [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017': [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}
df_chart = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_chart['total'] = df_chart[years].sum(axis=1)

print(df_chart)
chart_data_source = ColumnDataSource(data={})
chart_data_source.data = populate_table_source(df_chart)

years = ['2015', '2016', '2017']
# set up widgets
button = Button(label="Update", button_type="success")


p = figure(x_range=chart_data_source.data['fruits'],
           plot_height=250,
           plot_width=1000,
           title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           tools="hover,save",
           tooltips="$name: @$name",
           y_range=(0, 10) # can be updated if you assign it here
           )
p.vbar_stack(years,
             x='fruits',
             width=0.9,
             color=colors,
             source=chart_data_source,
             )

# p.y_range.start = 0
# p.y_range.end = 10 # can't be udpated if you assign it here

def update_data():
    data = {'fruits': ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries'],
            '2015': [np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5),
                     np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5)],
            '2016': [np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5),
                     np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5)],
            '2017': [np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5),
                     np.random.randint(5), np.random.randint(5)],
            }
    df_chart = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_chart['total'] = df_chart[years].sum(axis=1)
    chart_data_source.data = populate_table_source(df_chart)
    old_y_range = p.y_range.end
    p.y_range.end = old_y_range + 2


# Set up layout
button.on_click(update_data)
lo = layout(button, p)

curdoc().add_root(lo)
curdoc().title = "MVE"
```

Comment: Looks like a reference bug to me

Answer (score 0):

`Range1d` is an object, which has `start` and `end` properties, those are what you can update. Assigning one number to be the entire range does not make sense.

```
plot.y_range.end = max(chart_data_source.data['total'] + 25)
```

The error message you are seeing is due to something else, but it's not possible to speculate without more code.

Comment: that makes sense, but I also tried this and it doesn't work:  plot.y_range = Range1d(0, 175)  The y_range stays the same, but at least I don't get the warning message.

Comment: Best practice with Bokeh is always to make the smallest change possible, i.e. update properties on existing range objects (the way I show above), and don't replace range objects wholesale. If that's not working, you would need to post more code in order to speculate (really, you should always post a minimal reproducing example, as asked for)